# Add new AFHTTPRequestOperation with dependency on existing request

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Sending few post request using

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                      parameters:(id)parameters
                         success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                         failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

I want to perform one get request once all of the above request have processed so I have created `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and adding dependency as

```
for (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation in manager.operationQueue.operations ) {        
        [AFHTTPRequestOperationObject addDependency:operation];
    }
    [manager.operationQueue addOperation: AFHTTPRequestOperationObject];
```

But the operation is performed before the completion of existing post request.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `NSOperation` dependencies to solve this problem. In your case, later operations rely on processing with `completionBlock` but `NSOperationQueue` and AFNetworking both consider that work a side effect.

`completionBlock` is:

> the block to execute **after the operation’s main task is completed**.

(my emphasis).

In the case of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, "the operation’s main task" is "making an HTTP request". The "main task" **doesn't include** parsing JSON, persisting data, checking HTTP status codes, etc. - that's all handled in `completionBlock`.

To perform one request after other requests have processed, you'll need to make that request in the completion handler, once you've verified you have all the data you need to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

While using `OperationQueues`, it is not necessary that the responses will be received in the same order as the requests made. You will have to make sure that you make the `GET`request after complete execution of multiple `POST` requests. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474422/send-a-bunch-of-requests-one-by-one) explains the process to perform the operations serially with a completionHandler (which in your case should be the `GET` request that you want to execute at the completion of the `POST` requests.)

Comment: I don't want to execute post request sequentially. Whats the use of using queue for sequential execution. If I wanted to execute them in sequence I would have used sequential queues.I just want to make sure all request processed before one specific request. I don't mind earlier request working in parallel

Answer (score 0):

It appears that AFHTTPRequestOperation(s) complete as soon as the HTTP call is made and returns.  The success and failure blocks are called after these operations are complete.  So if you have NSOperation A dependent on B which is a AFHTTPRequestOperation then you may see B run, followed by A, followed by B's success block.  Seems to work if you create a "finished" operation and make A dependent on it.  Then have B enqueue the "finished" operation for running when B calls its success or failure block.  The "finished" operation in effect signals A that B has done all you wanted it to do.